# Delete object from list via firebase rest api

Tags: firebase

Currently I can't seem to find a way to delete an object from firebase list via REST api. For example I am trying to remove this from the list:
https://mrdapper.firebaseio.com/v0/users/41/favs.json?orderBy=%22id%22&equalTo=107657061

Posting a DELETE request doesn't work with query parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't delete with a query, (although that would be awesome). But you can use the results to send a DELETE request.

Do a GET:

```
GET https://mrdapper.firebaseio.com/v0/users/41/favs.json?orderBy=%22id%22&equalTo=107657061
```

This will return the object and you can send a DELETE request for each item it returns.

```
DELETE https://mrdapper.firebaseio.com/v0/users/41/favs/<returned-id>.json
```

Now, you may not like sending one delete request per object. But, with your data structure this is necessary.

**If you'd like to easily query and delete items, you could try this data structure:**

```
/users/$user_id
/userFavs/$user_id/$fav_id
```

Store the `favs` in it's own location under the root. This will allow you to retrieve `user` data without always getting the `favs`.

For `userFavs` if you key off `userid` and the `favid` you can easily query and delete.

```
{
  "userFavs": {
    "41": {
      "107657061": {
        "note_count": 43633
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can easily get all of the the user's favorites by specifying the user's id. If you need to delete by an id, that is also a key. So you can now DELETE without querying.

```
DELETE https://mrdapper.firebaseio.com/v0/userFavs/41/107657061.json
```

Comment: I tried that as well but the individual object url returns null.
https://mrdapper.firebaseio.com/v0/users/41/K4MoCH14oh4gkvI2wCq.json